# How to understand import in python?

Tags: python, import

I have `a.py` and `b.py` in the same directory. In a.py the code is

```
A = 'a1'

from b import B

print(B)
```

In b.py the code is

```
B = 'b1'

from a import A

print(A)
```

Now run a.py, the result is

```
b1
a1
b1
```

I don't understand.  Will somebody explain it? Thanks!

Comment: Btw, it is a *cyclic* import.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to focus on order of execution. This is  combined with a cyclic import.

The cyclic rules are stated in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/744373/6881240), which I disagree is a duplicate:

1. If a module has not been imported yet, execute it.
2. Otherwise, just return it, regardless of whether its original import completed.

Now, order of execution:

1. Run `A`
2. `A` imports `b`, which does not exist, so is executed.
3. `B` imports `B`, which does not exist (as an import) and is executed.
4. A new `A` runs. This time when `B` is imported though,  it already exists and returned. Luckily we already declared `b1`. Things would have gotten weird if we changed it after the import statement for example. Things would have broken if we declared it first after the import.
5. `A` completes its run.
6. `B` completes its run.
7. The initial a completes its run.

That is the order of print statements you are getting. It's important to note execution is completely linear here.

Comment: So, there is no single solution to this problem? I guess every language will get into this problem. Just curious :-)

Comment: @Nishant Well, if you do no nothing you get stuck i an import loop, so as a language designer you either break the loop somehow, or disallow it completely. From a completely theoretical standpoint, it may be "right" to just let this run forever.